# KDE wallet asks for password

Tags: password, kde

I'm a complete Linux Virgin..my b/f sadly passed away almost 4 years ago and he did all my techy stuff. I decided to update my version a couple of days ago to Ubuntu 16.04.6LTS and when I log in, 3 separate windows from KDE wallet asks for a password..I use my log in password but really is annoying, can you tell me in steps how to alter this or am I stuck with it? I have read others have this problem but am really apprehensive about altering anything without assistance. Would someone please take me through step by step what to do.

Comment: Sorry you lost your boyfriend. My wife and I keep talking about what will happen when I pass away. I keep telling her that our friend will help, but...what if he dies!? I'll show her askubuntu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KDE Wallet is a password manager built into KDE.  It is not essential to the operating system and can be easily disabled:

- Open System Settings
- Navigate to **Personalization > Account Details > KDE Wallet**
- Uncheck the box **"Enable the KDE wallet subsystem"**
- Click **Apply** and enter your credentials.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Nmath..it worked.

Comment: I still get a window asking for a password to connect to my Virgin Wifi....can you help me with this please?

Comment: I think I shall just leave it as it is and enter my password when connecting..im looking now to see where i mark this as "Accepted" this is my first visit here so I apologise for not getting it quite right.

Comment: I'm a born-again Linux version and am also trying to get more control over password management on my first custom built machine. Currently, I have a password when the computer first turns on (I think this is the hard drive encryption I selected during OS installation), my main storage drive also requires a password to open the file system. the wifi inconsistently asks for a password at startup, and I don't even have KDE wallet configured.
Seems like there are some redundancies here. Wouldn't the initial hard-drive encryption be enough? Please post a relevant Stack Exchange link if available.

Comment: I don't see "Account Details". There's "Online Accounts" but nothing there.